# ExtJS: Response of too fast handler sometimes fail

Tags: asp.net, json, extjs, ashx

I have a strange problem, that appears not always, but sometimes with the same request.
On my website (localhost) I have an ExtJS store with autoloading, and after page load (pushing F5 button) it reads JSON from some handler (***.ashx) from server. Handler gets data from DB and serializes it it JSON. It works 4 times of 5 pressing F5. 5th time json-reader shows success=false and 0 length data.

If I use time delay in handler, such as:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

It works 49 times of 50. But it is weird to set a latency in my response, when I try to make website faster.

Please help or ask me if there is not enough info about a problem!

Here is sample of my js:

```
storePrefixes.on({
        'beforeload': function () {
           //...
        },
        'load': {
            fn: function() {
                if (storePrefixes.data.items.length > 0)
                    // ... working with response
                else 
                    // here is a problem
            },
            single: true
        }
    });
```

And there is server code:

```
    <%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="GetPrefixesInRD" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using BCR.BLL;

public class GetPrefixesInRD : IHttpHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IReadOnlySessionState
{
    private readonly PrefixNewBLL prefixeBLL = new PrefixNewBLL();
    private readonly Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer();

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var prefixes = prefixeBLL.GetPrefixesByExistPrefixInAccountingDocs(null, 1, false);
        prefixes.Sort((x, y) => String.CompareOrdinal(x.Prefix, y.Prefix));

        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.BufferOutput = true;
        serializer.Serialize(context.Response.Output, new { root = prefixes, total = prefixes.Count });
        context.Response.Flush();
        context.Response.End();
    }

    public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }
}
```

Comment: If slowing your server code helps, the problem is with your server code. Showing that code would get you a better answer. I suspect your database would be locking on something. Do you write out any exceptions that occur during data access?

Comment: Thanks for answer, but no exceptions rises in my server code, I've just checked it. Also I edited my post with my server code for better help

Comment: What is the server responding? You could have a look at the JSON data with Chrome in the Developer Tools in the Network tab and check the request. That will at least help you determine wether the server response was faulty when Ext gave you the error, or if the problem was somewhere in your client.

Answer (score 0):

When debugging, I would check this.isLoading() to see if it is still trying to load on the odd man out.  It might be better to move everything to the datachanged event.  If you need to analyze the store, use console.dir(Ext.apply({}, this)); to get a snapshot at runtime.